# What are the special features of the Ferrari F1 Racer 1:8 kit?

Tags: sets

I found a good price on the [Ferrari F1 Racer 1:8](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8674-1) kit. From the picture of the box cover, it would seem that the steering wheel can turn the wheels, but I cannot identify any other moving features.

- Is this a Technic model or just a display model, which happens to use a lot of Technic parts?
- If I am after a model containing many useful Technic parts for use in custom creations, is this a kit to avoid?
- Do many of the side panels appear in other models or were they custom made for this kit and therefore, might have limited value outside of the box design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider the model as a Technic one (it's built as such), but very poor as far as functions go: steering and the ubiquitous cylinder block, I don't even see any suspension.

You can see the parts included at [peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/8674-1?withpics=yes) or [bricklink](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=8674-1) and judge for yourself if the parts interest you or not. As a licensed set, it's likely its price is inflated to cover the license cost, so I'm not sure it's the best parts pack.

The panels are standard Technic panels (with stickers), although LEGO has discontinued them since then in favour or more robust panels which participate to the model structure in their own right.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Instructions for 8674-1 - Ferrari F1 Racer 1:8](http://bricks.argz.com/ins/8674-1) you can see that the pistons also go up and down and the body can be removed.  From the box picture posted the set was part of the [LEGO Racers](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?Page=2&theme=Racers), specifically the [Ferrari subtheme](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Racers&subtheme=Ferrari).